# Intent.ACTION_VIEW recognizes every single file as a pdf

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

Here is my code

```
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(fileUri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

So, it opens a file that I specify within my app. First few files I tested it on were - pdf ones and it worked just fine. And now, and I know it is complete bonkers, every time I choose anything different from pdf - it apparently tries to use a program for the pdf files to open the chosen file and gives me this message

```
The document cannot be opened because it is not a valid PDF document
```

Funny thing :) Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Intent.setType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29) to set the mimetype of each file that you are trying to open. So that only app that can handle the particular mimetype will be opened

Edit: You can use [MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#getMimeTypeFromExtension%28java.lang.String%29) to get the Mimetype of the file.

Comment: who knows what file i will open next? I thought this Intent.ACTION_VIEW should take care of it, am i wrong?

Comment: ACTION_VIEW will just find any activity that has registered for that filter. Also see my edit

Comment: well, thanks, the initial problem was solved :) now i have another one but it is hole different story ))

Comment: i was talking about the viewer. If your app is not going to be the viewer you dont need to declare filter in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

try specifying explicitly the type of type you want to open.. for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filename);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

or if for some reason you wanted to email the pdf you could do

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```